# How to debug Visual Studio Team Services unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops

In my team, Visual Studio Team Services (formerly Visual Studio Online / Team Foundation Service) is configured to automatically build the solution and run all the unit tests of the solution, at each check-in.

There is a test that succeeds in my local Visual Studio but not in Team Services: how can i do to have more information about the test that failed? Is it possible to manually run the test in Team Services?

Comment: Have you opened the test results and downloaded them? Debugging non-deterministic tests that work locally and fail on build servers (local or online) is a pain :). Maybe you can add some logging.

Comment: Does the test use any dependencies?

Comment: In the Build/Log section of VS online there is a "Download drop as zip" button, but it made me download the whole solution and no information about the tests. Yes, the test use dependencies.

Comment: Are the dependencies the tests use available to the hosted build machine?

Comment: Yes. I found the solution: the test works locally, but not if I launch the entire set of tests. So I could understand what was the error. Thank you.

Comment: How did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue with intermittently failing tests.  Visual Studio Team Services says the tests failed, but not why - not on the build's Summary, Log, or Diagnostics tabs, and not when you "Download all logs as zip".  However, you can get this information inside Visual Studio.

In Visual Studio, go to the menu View > Team Explorer.  Click Builds.  You should see a list of recent builds.  Double click the failed build.  You can now expand the failing tests and see **why** they failed.

Comment: In the "View Summary" section, there is a blue link writtern something like this "buildguest@BUILD-0030 2015-02-04 17:59:49_Any CPU_Debug," Click on it, Test Result panel will pop up and all test cases show.